# How do i scan each character in a user input and compare it to the second integer they input?

Tags: python

probably my last post for a while but I've been having some trouble with another one of my codes.

so for context, the program that I want to make is that the user inputs a 3 character integer and a single integer separated by a space.

the code:

```
a,b = input().split()
if a[0] and a[1] and a[-1] == b:
    print("Jackpot!")
else:
    print("Nah")
```

example of an  input:

```
777 7
```

the output it gives if each character in the first input is the same as the second in the same line.

```
Jackpot!
```

another example of an input:

```
177 7
```

the output if one of the characters in the first input isn't the same as the second input:

```
Nah
```

So far so good, the code i have currently reads each character in the input **EXCEPT** the second character. so if i input '177 7' it returns "Nah" as expected, same as if I input 771 7. But if I input for example:

```
717 7
```

it returns "Jackpot!" when it shouldn't. Any advice on what I could do? How do i let my code read the 2nd character in the integer so that it should return the appropriate response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what logic you have used. But to process this you can use sets.
For example ->

```
set(string2) == set(string1)
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
all([b == int(digit) for digit in str(a)])
```

This will basically check that all digit are equal to the given digit `b`.

Answer (score 2):

Due to operator precedence, equality is checked for the last integer character only.

```
# Equality checked for a[-1] == b only
if a[0] and a[1] and a[-1] == b:
    print("Jackpot!")
```

For checking all the three integer characters, use:

```
if (a[0] == b) and (a[1] == b) and (a[-1] == b):
    print("Jackpot!")
```